# Correct way to write the closed linear span of $\{2ax^3 + ax^2 + bx + b\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

(disclaimer: this is a newbie question)

I have the set $L=\{ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d \in R_4[X]|a=2b,c=d\}$, how can I write $L$ as a closed linear span?

EDIT: The question has been rephrased.

Comment: What are $a,b$? fixed? arbitrary?

Comment: $a,b$ are arbitrary numbers

Comment: I wasn't precise enough. Is $\{2ax^3+ax^2+bx+b\}$ the set that just contains this one polynomial (and $a,b$ are fixed beforehand) or is it supposed to be the set containing all expressions of the *form* $2ax^3+ax^2+bx+b$ for some scalars $a,b$?

Comment: @Thorgott Correct, my mistake, this is the expression in the form ${2ax^3 + ax^2 + bx + b}$ for some scalars $a,b$

Comment: I have rephrased the question

Comment: It seems that you require $a=2b$, so there is only one "degree of freedom" for $a,b$, and similarly $c=d$, so they might just as well be written as a single variable.  If you have occasion to edit your Question, I'd encourage you to be more economical in how you phrase it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you are looking at the subspace
$$V=\{P\in\mathbb{R}_{\le 3}[X]\vert \exists a,b\in\mathbb{R}\colon P(X)=2aX^3+aX^2+bX+b\}.$$
Note that every $P\in V$ can be written as $a(2X^3+X^2)+b(X+1)$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. This implies that $\{2X^3+X^2,X+1\}$ is a generating set for $V$. In fact, these two polynomials form a basis of $V$.

Comment: You are correct! how could I have missed that \*facepalm*

Answer (score 1):

A polynomial is entirely determined by its coefficient. So, the linear span is : 
A=$$(x^3,x^2,x,1)$$
You can right every polynomial with degree $3$ as a linear combination of $x^3,x^2,x,1$, which are vectors in the vector space of polynomials. But you can also generate all the polynomial with degree $3$ with $A$, with constant coefficient added, for example : 
$$A'=(ax^3,bx^2,x,1)$$

Comment: The coefficients in my question are in a certain way (2a, a, b, b), I am not talking about the entire vector space of polynomials

Answer (score 1):

$\text{Span} \{2ax^3, ax^2, bx,b\}$ refers to the set of all polynomials of the form $\lambda_1 (2ax_3) + \lambda_2 (ax^2)+\lambda_3 (bx) + \lambda_4 b$ for constants $a,b, \lambda_1, ...,\lambda_4.$ Since $2ax^3+ax^2+bx+b = (1)(2ax_3+ ( 1)(ax^2)+(1)bx)+(1)(b), 2ax^3+ax^2+bx+b\in \text{Span} \{2ax^3, ax^2, bx,b\},$

which is not the same thing as saying they're equal as $\text{Span}\{2ax^3, ax^2, bx,b\}$ is a set and the given polynomial is an element of that set.

Comment: Thank you william, what is the linear span of this expression?